# Duplicate Symbol Error for architecture i386?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am getting following error while build app.

I have checked the following things but still error not gone

```
1. file exists twice.
2. Import ".m" intead of .h
3. `File missing`
4. Duplicate function
```

Any other thing too check?

```
 duplicate symbol _downloadCompleted in:
   /Xcode/DerivedData/WAI2go-ckzrqcnbjsisokcplqkvzwxhclrg/Build/Intermediates/WAI2go.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WAI2go.build/Objects-normal/i386/Middleware.o
    Xcode/DerivedData/WAI2go-ckzrqcnbjsisokcplqkvzwxhclrg/Build/Intermediates/WAI2go.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WAI2go.build/Objects-normal/i386/ZipArchive.o
duplicate symbol _onDownloadCompleted in:
   Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAI2go-ckzrqcnbjsisokcplqkvzwxhclrg/Build/Intermediates/WAI2go.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WAI2go.build/Objects-normal/i386/Middleware.o
   Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAI2go-ckzrqcnbjsisokcplqkvzwxhclrg/Build/Intermediates/WAI2go.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WAI2go.build/Objects-normal/i386/ZipArchive.o
duplicate symbol _onImageDownloadCompleted in:
    Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAI2go-ckzrqcnbjsisokcplqkvzwxhclrg/Build/Intermediates/WAI2go.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WAI2go.build/Objects-normal/i386/Middleware.o
    Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WAI2go-ckzrqcnbjsisokcplqkvzwxhclrg/Build/Intermediates/WAI2go.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WAI2go.build/Objects-normal/i386/ZipArchive.o
ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: hahaha... very frequent bug shown by compiler. :P   Try everything, clean, file path change, check for multiple #imports etc. Sometimes it works some time doesn't. And best of luck. And please post the answer if you find some hard n fast solution.

Comment: Did you try to delete the derived data?

Comment: Yes man not a issue of this

Comment: Are the mentioned variables global?

Comment: Yes vairables are global. i removed and it and it started working

Comment: OK I will add this as an answer.

Comment: yaa sure i will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global variables can cause this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have two different files with the same Interface name.

It happened when you use a custom SDK that contain a class you already imported to the project